# Data Generation Plan connected fields

Tags: visual-studio-2008, data-generation

Is it possible to have 2 fields with the same data for a Data Generation Plan?  For example, the table aspnet_roles has 2 fields RoleName and LoweredRoleName and I want them to show the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but maybe not in the way you're expecting. If you want random strings in one and a lowercase version in the other then not really, but if you have a table available that the sequential data-bound generator can use, you can get something similar.